# input changes getting previous value

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the previous value in console when i write in the input, how can i get the actual value?

```js
const input1 = document.querySelector('#a')

input1.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a" />
```

[image]

Comment: use a different event? change or keydown?

Comment: event `input` is a good bet

Comment: @evolutionxbox  yes, i tryed both.

Comment: @ITgoldman YES, is working with 'input' event! i hope this answer would be usefull to someone in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try eventListener `input`. `Keydown` is fired before the character is added to the field, which is why you don't see the 4 after typing 1234. (An if you prevent the default action of keydown, the character is never added.) `keyup` is also fired after the character is added.

```js
const input1 = document.querySelector('#a')

input1.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to change keydown to keyup event listener. It will work for your case.

```
input1.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
   console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

A better way will be if you use event listener "input".

```
input1.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
   console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

hello freind i want provide you how to listen input event

if this case have many method:

1)

```
<input name="name" id="a"/>
document.querySelector("input#a").addEventListener("input",function(event){
console.log(event.target.value);})
```